# Class instance variables not inherited "activerecord-import" rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activerecord-import

I'm using `activerecord-import (1.0.3)`.
There is a way to override the `sequence_name` of a model in order to have import taking it into account:

```rb
class A < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.sequence_name = "my_new_seq"
end
```

However when I do:

```rb
class B < A
  ...
end

B.import! data # it uses B default sequence_name
```

The way to get the right `sequence_name` used is to specify it once again:

```
class B < A
  self.sequence_name = "my_new_seq"
end

B.import! data # uses B good sequence_name
```

How can I get this value to be passed to subclasses?

### Response

Class A is an abstract class. sequence_name should be defined the following way:

```rb
class A < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  
  class << self
    def sequence_name
      "my_new_seq"
    end
  end
 
end
```

Comment: If it really is backed by class instance variable then they are not inherited unlike class varaibles. It really just is an instance variable that belongs to the Class instance (aka the singleton class or eigenclass).

Comment: @max it is definitely a class instance variable [`ActiveRecord::ModelSchema::ClassMethods::sequence_name=`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/sequence_name%3D) sets `@sequence_name`

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky - explains why I didn't find it since I was looking for the method in the gem.

Comment: I guess a potential solution could be overriding the `sequence_name` class method in `A`. `def self.sequence_name; "my_new_seq"; end` but is it really worth it VS just doing it explicitly?

Comment: @max I am not too proud to correct myself. I have no idea why the OP is experiencing this issue because `sequence_name()` uses `base_class.sequence_name` unless one is set explicitly [Docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/sequence_name). Since `ApplicationRecord` is an abstract class `B.base_class #=> A`. Pierre-Louis can you confirm `B.sequence_name` does not equal `"my_new_seq"` but `B.base_class` does equal `A`?

Comment: So with the current state, `B.sequence_name != "my_new_seq"` but `B.base_class == B` I don't know exactly why... I'm pretty new to rails..

Comment: Can you add the output of `B.ancestors` as well as `B.method(:sequence_name).source_location`

Comment: `B.ancestors` does show: `[B, ..,  A, ...]`.
`B.method(:sequence_name).source_location` shows `[".../gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb", 294]`

Oh, I just realised that `A` is an abstract class, can it be why?

Comment: That is exactly why.