# Self shorthand doesn't behave the same way than class << self rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, self

I would like to understand why in this scenario, subclasses of A won't heritate from `sequence_name`.

```rb
class A < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.sequence_name = "my_seq"
end
```

And why when defined as follow they will.

```rb
class A < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
 
  class << self
    def sequence_name
      "my_seq"
    end
  end
end
```

I thought that `self.method` was equivalent to:

```rb
class << self
  def method; end
end
```

Comment: `self.sequence_name =` just _calls_ a method, it doesn’t define anything. `def sequence_name` on the other hand _defines_ a method. (without calling it)

Comment: BTW this still will not solve your [Previous Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65924291/class-instance-variables-not-inherited-activerecord-import-rails) due to the fact the `A` is an abstract class. `B.base_class #=> B`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought that `self.method` was equivalent to:
>
> ```
> class << self
>   def method; end
> end
> ```

Not quite.

You can create a class method by defining an instance method in the class' singleton class: (that's what class methods really are)

```
class A
  class << self
    def method; end
  end
end
```

Or by using the `def self.` syntax: (equivalent to the above)

```
class A
  def self.method; end
end
```

To *call* the method from within the class, you'd use:

```
class A
  method
end
```

And if your method is a *setter*, you have to add an explicit receiver, e.g.:

```
class A
  self.method = 123
end
```

That looks a bit like the `def self.` syntax for defining a class method, but note that there's no `def` in here.

---

You can rewrite your working code as:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
 
  def self.sequence_name
    "my_seq"
  end
end
```